# how can I make items that match the height of the container and card that I have

Tags: flutter

> how can i make like this?
> [image]

> I use Expansion Tiles
> My Code :

```
Container(
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, left: 30),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                    'Jhon Doe',
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 22,
                    width: 70,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                      color: const Color(0XFF00B383),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1),
                        child: Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                            'User',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              'Level',
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                const Icon(
                  Icons.level,
                  size: 18,
                  color: Color(0XFF3F414E),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Boss',
                ),
              ],
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Detailed',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
     ExpansionTile(
     title: const Text('Phone'),
     children: List.generate(state.user.boss.length, (index) {      
     return Card(
      child: Text('+91 84785783458')
     );
     }
     )

          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: 20,
        height: ,
        child: const Text('data'),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

> I am using ExpansionTile, how can I create it? , I am using ExpansionTile, how can I create it? I am using ExpansionTile, how can I create it? I am using ExpansionTile, how can I create it? I am using ExpansionTile, how can I create it? I am using ExpansionTile, how can I create it?

Comment: Can you share the existing code here, so we can run it on dartpad?

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of detail, and does not make it easy to solve your issue. At the very least, you need to include code you've already written so people can help you figure out where it's going wrong (or help guide you in another direction).

Comment: i already added it @paulo

Comment: i already added it @nchopra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is the code you want. As a child of `Container`, use `Container` to create a frame. Add your design code in it!

```
 Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 100,
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFD50000),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: 190,
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(8), bottomRight: Radius.circular(8)),
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ///Implements your Designed
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

[image]

Comment: what about the dark red element that sits on the left side? @jungwon

Comment: Do you have a color code?

Comment: FF0000 @jungwon

Comment: I modified the code but it's not the same color as you want. Just find the code of the same color and enter it.

Comment: Great job, you saved me the day, I got stuck in a stack loop that I forgot the child container padding was really helpful. Thank you @jungwon

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 100,
      color: Colors.red,
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: Container(
        width: 260,
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.red.shade200,
        child: ExpansionTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.people, color: Colors.white, size: 30),
          iconColor: Colors.white,
          title: Text('Jhon Dee', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(title: Text('+91 999 000 1111', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what about the red border? @sabahat-hussain-qureshi

Comment: what about the dark red element that sits on the left side? @sabahat-hussain-qureshi

Comment: Check out i update the answer @AhmedSalavy